# Can i refire the trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a future callout method(calls external server) in a trigger. I am calling external server in future callout method and passing data(Trigger.new) to it. If the external server is down. Is there any way to fire trigger with same data one more time when the external server is up.

```
    trigger accountOpTrigger on Account (after insert) {
       String accountsJSON = JSON.serializePretty(Trigger.New);
       OPAccount.opAccount(accountsJSON);
      }


    public with sharing class OPAccount {
@future (callout=true)
public static void opAccount(String accountsJSON){
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        Http http = new Http();
        System.debug('Calling Openprise cloud');    
        request.setEndpoint('https://op1.openprisecloud.com/daass/pipelines/0000/processRecords?apiKey=*************************');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setBody(accountsJSON);
        try{ 
            response = http.send(request);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug(ex);
        }
        if(response != null){

            System.debug('Success status code: '+response.getStatus()); 
        }
        else{
            System.debug('No response from Openprise');
        }
   }    
}
```

Comment: You have a future callout method in a trigger? that can't be good Vijaybabu. Can you please post your code so we can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

I think Andrew answers this question pretty well in this somewhat duplicate post: [Rerun a Async Apex Job](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7596/rerun-a-async-apex-job)

Typically you could implement some code that could do exponential back-off like you might in a REST call, but since you are needing to maintain your Trigger.new data throughout the re-tries, you would need to build something custom to store those records and probably some kind of status to check for success/failure of a batch, and when to retry.

As Carlos mentioned, putting external calls into triggers is a recipe for eventual disaster and it would make more sense to delegate the external call and the processing of those results to a less time sensitive mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to fire trigger with same data one more time when the external server is up.

**No**. You cannot re-fire a trigger based on any external criteria. Triggers always fire whenever a record changes.

Also, you should re-consider your approach of firing a `future` method from Trigger. And the reason is because by the time your method receives the records from Trigger, the records may have been already changed.

What you are necessarily looking here is to build a *retry logic*. In these scenarios, you should instead try to design your callouts using [Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm). This approach will allow you to get the latest of the records that you need to pass to your external web service as well as *retry* with another scheduled job in case of any failures. This is just a pointer towards how you should build it, but the actual implementation depends on your use case.